# Distribute App Center builds to Google Play including debug symbols and mapping file upload

Tags: android, google-play-console, debug-symbols, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I managed to set up Visual Studio App Center to build my Xamarin.Forms project and distribute the Android build to Google Play.

It works, but Google Play Console warns about missing Native debug symbols and the ReTrace mapping file mappings.txt from the code shrinker - both can be uploaded manually (app bundle explorer), but how can I download them from App Center or even automate this?

---

There are a few interesting github tickets and other search results:
https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/130#issuecomment-498756778
https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/75#issuecomment-493184790

But nothing seems to work. Only if I set up my build to distribute automatically, the app-center-distribute task writes this to the log:
##[warning]Cannot find any file based on /Users/runner/work/1/a/mapping/**/mapping.txt.

From my understanding this means the mapping file wasn't included in the build artifacts.

Any suggestions? How are you doing this?